# Efficient way to run a ML model for multiple tasks

Tags: python

I'm running a [scheduler](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) in a script that has different kind of tasks in it. These tasks are using a trained ML model. So that I managed to load the model once, in the main script. Then pass it to tasks when they run.

But it kinda became a complex structure and hard to maintain. So I thought what if I run another API-like script in localhost using flask and run the model there. Then just post requests to it whenever and wherever (in local machine) I need to use the model.

Is this a neat and professional solution?

I don't know if SO is the right place to ask this but I couldn't figure out anywhere else. Thanks.

Comment: It'd be easier to just separate those different concerns into different packages within your codebase than to start figuring out an API server.

Comment: This is probably a better question for software engineering exchange. Stackoverflow is more of debugging code. More theory type questions are better on software engineering exchange

Comment: @AKX they are actually seperated, like I have a package for each task that I create instances from them. And one script that handles the scheduler. But if you say this is a better way to do it rather than an API server, I will think about it more. The API server will be very simple and only run in local though.

Comment: Thanks, @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim. I haven't heard about it. I will consider it next time.